Conditions in functions in pandas
I am new to Pandas and trying to figure out how to create/use functions, perform simple if-else statements. I wrote the following function average_shares(), but it doesn't work as I expect (because it should be written for rows, not columns, but I don't get it/ don't know how to fix the following code. In a simple non-pandas world I would write for i in range(len(column)): do the following. In pandas tutorials they didn't use for loops, they used apply(); they created functions with a parameter row (why not dataframe df as parameter?). I tried to do the same and it didn't work. So overall, I just don't know how to do a simple thing in pandas and I hoped maybe someone could show me.
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1], 'week': [1, 1, 2], 'order': [2, 4, 3]})
df['index'] = df.groupby(['id', 'week']).cumcount()+1 #can be many id-s (not only id=1)
df['share'] = df['order']/df.groupby(['id', 'week'])['order'].transform('sum')
df['len'] = (df.groupby(['id', 'week']))['order'].transform('count')

def average_shares(df):
    if df['repeats']>2:
        df = df[(df['share'])>0.05 & (df['share']<0.95)]
        df['share_1'] = df[df['index']==1].groupby('id')['share'].transform('mean')
        df['share_2'] = df[df['index']==2].groupby('id')['share'].transform('mean')
    elif df['repeats']==2:
        df['share_1'] = df[df['index']==1].groupby('id')['share'].transform('mean')
        df['share_2'] = df[df['index']==2].groupby('id')['share'].transform('mean')
    elif df['repeats']<2:
        df['share_1'] = df['share']
        df['share_2'] = 0
    return df['share_1'], df['share_2']

df['share_1'], df['share_2'] = zip(*df.apply(average_shares, axis=1))

The task sounds as

In the dataframe there are columns: id, week, order, share. Each week can be repeated more than once. For each id, share_1 is an average share of the first occurrences of weeks, and share_2 is an average share of the second occurrences. If for some id a week is repeated more than 2 times, then before averaging, the rows with a share >0.95 and <0.05 are discarded. If some week is not repeated, then the average share of the first occurrence is equal to the share itself, the average share of the second occurrence is 0.

Here is the data:
|input        |calculated       |I need to calculate             |
|-------------|-----------------|---------------- ---------------|
|id|week|order|index|share  |len|average share_1 |average share_2|
|--|----|-----|-----|-------|---|----------------|---------------|
|1 |  1 |2    |1    |2/(2+4)|2  |(2/6+1)/2 = 0.66|(4/6+0)/2 =0.33|
|1 |  1 |4    |2    |4/(2+4)|2  |(2/6+1)/2 = 0.66|(4/6+0)/2 =0.33|
|1 |  2 |3    |1    |1      |1  |(2/6+1)/2 = 0.66|(4/6+0)/2 =0.33|


len = number of repeats of the same week
index = order of apperance of the repeats
share = order devided by the sum of the week orders
share_1 = average share among weeks with index 1 (with the same id)
share_2 = average share among weeks with index 2 (with the same id)


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a Q&A site, but you haven't asked a question. If you do have something you want to ask, please read [ask] and [edit] to clarify. If you're looking for help with your code, you'll need to provide a [mre] including input data, expected output, and actual output as text, not a picture. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

I see you edited to add a question, but it's too vague. Questions here need to be specific. Please do take the [tour] to learn more. You might also want to read Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

Thanks for the comment! The thing is that I studied some online courses related to Pandas (on Kaggle, datacamp) and then I tried to solve a task by myself. But it turned out it's not that easy. In a simple non-pandas world I would write "for i in range(len(column)): do the following". In pandas tutorials they didn't use for loops, they used apply(), they created functions with a parameter "row" (why not dataframe "df" as parameter?). I tried to do the same and it didn't work.So overall, I just don't know how to do a simple thing in pandas and I hoped maybe someone could show me

Oh, you don't know how to use .apply() properly! (No offense, we've all been there.) Check out the user guide: Function application. Maybe you should try a simpler example first to ease yourself into it.

The problem states In the dataframe there are columns: id, week, order, share. That makes it sound like share is in the input, but you've shown it as being calculated. Where does the definition for that column come from?

I know how to calculate share, no errors accured: it's a ratio of the order for the week to the sum of all orders for that week

I need the shares from 0.05 to 0.95, the very high and very low shares are discarded

0.05 and 0.95, fixed, thanks!

In your example, why should share_2 be 0.33? I'd think that it should equal 0.66 == (4/6+0)/1. The denominator is 1 because there is only one second-week.

The average share is 0.33 because week 2 only appears once in the data, so I assume that orders for the second appearance of week 2 are 0. I then average the shares that were in the period of the second appearances of weeks 1 and 2.

Sure; I've modified my demonstration to use a fixed week count.


trying to figure out how to create/use functions, perform simple if-else statements

This already needs to be re-thought. Numpy/Pandas don't generally talk in "if/else" - they talk in boolean predicate vectors, essentially arrays of True/False. This is done for performance purposes.

In pandas tutorials they didn't use for loops, they used apply()

Both of those should be avoided. Instead use direct vectorised methods.

I tried to do the same and it didn't work. So overall, I just don't know how to do a simple thing in pandas

To be fair, what you're doing is not very simple. It's a fairly tricky multi-step operation.
You also need to significantly expand your input dataset to cover more test cases, including longer ID groups that both meet and do not meet the 5% criterion.
For example,
import pandas as pd

# More rows have been added for the 5% test case.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':    (1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 2),
    'week':  (1, 1, 2,  2, 2, 2, 1),
    'order': (2, 4, 3, 40, 5, 1, 6),
})

# share is order divided by the sum of the week orders
by_id_week = df.groupby(['id', 'week'])
df['share'] = df['order']/by_id_week['order'].transform('sum')

# If for some ID a week is repeated more than two times, then before
# averaging, discard the rows with a share < 0.05 or > 0.95
to_average = df.copy()
to_average['n_weeks'] = by_id_week['order'].transform('count')
to_average.query(
    expr='(n_weeks <= 2) | ((share >= 0.05) & (share <= 0.95))',
    inplace=True,
)
to_average['week_idx'] = to_average.groupby(['id', 'week']).cumcount()

# share_1 is an average share of the first occurrences of weeks
# share_2 is an average share of the second occurrences
# etc.
week_count = 2
means_by_idx = (
    (
        to_average.groupby(['id', 'week_idx'])['share']
        .sum() / week_count
    )
    .unstack('week_idx')  # One column per week index
    .loc[:, :2]           # Only care about the first and second week
    .rename(columns={0: 'share_1', 1: 'share_2'})
)

# At this point, means_by_idx has one row per ID, and one column per week index.
# The row index is equal to the ID value, so we can merge on it.
df = pd.merge(
    left=df, right=means_by_idx,
    left_on='id', right_index=True,
)
print(df)


Thank you very much for your help!  I deeply appreciate it!
